# Matrix equation (esp. row vectors)

Tags: formatting, vertical-alignment, matrices

I'd like to write the matrix equation A = (x y) B (x y)^T, where (x y)^T is written as a column vector and B is a 2x2 matrix written as such. I can (almost) do this by, for example, the following:

```
A = (x \ y) \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix}
```

But I'd like the row vector (x y) to be aligned with the first row of the matrix B. How do I do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For consistency's sake, I would also use a `pmatrix` for the first matrix; then you can wrap the first `pmatrix` inside a `matrix` with an empty second row:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
A = 
  \begin{matrix}\begin{pmatrix}x & y\end{pmatrix}\\\mbox{}\end{matrix}
  \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix} 
  \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Come to think of it, is this type of equation typically formatted to have the row vector in line with the first row of the matrix?

Comment: @Matt: No. I have never seen it like that at least. Row vectors are usually just set in the same way as scalars.

Comment: Funny, I always do it this way by hand, but never considered typesetting it like this.

Comment: @Matt This would be mistaken for a kind of exponent; leave it in the middle. What would you do for the product of a 2x4 matrix by a 4x3 one?

Comment: @MarkS.Everitt, I always do it that way by hand too, but it just doesn't look right when typesetting. Sorry!